# Is it possible to use a callback function with .bind?

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

Is it possible to use a callback function with .bind?

The simplified example below returns `6() => 99` instead of `105` as I had expected.  Does it need to be constructed differently?  [MDN doesn't have a comparable example to use as a blueprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  Thanks so much for any input!

```js
"use strict";

let testObject = {
  valueOne: 1,
  valueTwo: 2,
  valueThree: 3
}

function addValues(bonusParameter) {
  return this.valueOne + this.valueTwo + this.valueThree + bonusParameter;
}

let finalAnswer = addValues.bind(testObject, () => 99);

console.log(finalAnswer());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're failing to actually call your `bonusParameter` so it is just being weirdly evaluated as a string.  Look below you can see it working properly.

```js
"use strict";

let testObject = {
  valueOne: 1,
  valueTwo: 2,
  valueThree: 3
}

function addValues(bonusParameter) {
  return this.valueOne + this.valueTwo + this.valueThree + bonusParameter(); // calling bonusParameter
}

let finalAnswer = addValues.bind(testObject, () => 99);

console.log(finalAnswer());
```

Comment: `weirdly`? nothing weird about it - it's how javascript works :p

Comment: Holy smokes you are 100% correct!  That makes perfect sense.  I stared at my code for 30 minutes and never caught that.

Comment: @JaromandaX - yeah, sorry, I was being a bit glib.  I more meant that sometimes the automatic type-conversion gives surprising or less than intuitive results.  I don't know exactly what I would have expected, but it was a bit surprising to me to see a number plus function evaluate essentially as `myNumber.toString() + myFunction.toString()`, but I suppose it's probably the most obvious solution when you think about it.  I guess I figured it would be something like `6[object Object]` or something, but in retrospect what actually happens does make more sense.